# Something is wrong with this community wiki author username

Tags: bug, display-names

I recently noticed [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). The 'author box' shows this:

[image]

However, clicking on the username takes me to [this profile](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/138112) - with 'not Pekka' as a username. Also, the correct username is shown in the post's revision history.

It's almost like an old version of the username is being somehow cached - but I'm pretty sure that that doesn't happen. What's different about this instance?